# Replacing part of the strtotime function in PHP with a variable

Tags: php

I was just wondering if it were possible to replace a part of the strtotime function line with a variable? What I mean is, when I have the following strtotime function:

```
$_expires = date('d M, Y G:i', strtotime('+12 days'));
```

is it possible to replace the '+12 days'-part with a variable to make it possible to use just one line which generates different dates in the future? Something like this:

```
$_variable1 = "+9 days";
$_expires = date('d M, Y G:i', strtotime('$_variable1'));
```

If it isn't, no big deal, just have to write a humongous piece of code. Just was wondering as it has gotten kinda grumpy when I tried it so far. If you need more info, pls let me know. Thanks a million!

Comment: `$_variable1 = "+9 days"; $_expires = date('d M, Y G:i', strtotime($_variable1));` — This should work just fine. Note that I've removed the quotes around `$_variable1`.

Comment: Have you tried it? Nope. Otherwise, you wouldn't be asking or you'd be saying there was an error.

Comment: @Fred: I did try it - "it has gotten kinda grumpy when I tried it so far". It didn't give me an error msg, just gave the wrong results, so there was no error msg to note here. And you give me a minus point for that? The mistake in this were the quotes and they were also the reason why I asked whether it was possible to do so. Maybe you want to read first before you judge...

Comment: @everybody else: thank you very much for helping me out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup, just leave off the quotes around the variable inside strtotime.

```
$_variable1 = "+9 days";
$_expires = date('d M, Y G:i', strtotime($_variable1));
```

Comment: Thanks a million - you just saved me a lot of work :)